# Spinner Issue in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have created a simple post application for displaying some posts using React.

When the application loads I'm making an API call and display some posts. 
After that when user clicks on anyone of these post , a detailed summary of post is shown.

Issue I' m facing is in loading the spinner:

When user clicks on post: inside **componentWillReceiveProps** I'm changing the state to  **spinning: true** and when the I get the detailed data from API about the post I change the state to  **spinning: false**.
However my spinner only works when I first time clicks on the post after that it doesn't works.

FULLPOST.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner/Spinner';
import './FullPost.css';

class FullPost extends Component {
    state ={
        loadedPost: null,
        spinning: false
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.id){
           this.setState({
            spinning: true
           })
        }

    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.id){
            axios.get("/posts/" + this.props.id).then( response => {
               if(!this.state.loadedPost || (this.state.loadedPost && this.state.loadedPost.id !== this.props.id)){
                   setTimeout(function(){
                    this.setState({
                        loadedPost: response.data,
                        spinning: false
                    }) 
                   }.bind(this)
                   ,2000)
               }     
            })
        }
    }
    render () {
        let post;
        if(!this.props.id){
            console.log("1")
             post = <p style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Please select a Post!</p>;
        }
        else{
            console.log("2")
            post = <Spinner /> 
        }
        if(this.props.id){
            console.log("3")
            if(this.state.loadedPost){
                console.log("4")
                post = (
                    <div className="FullPost">
                        <h1>{this.state.loadedPost.title}</h1>
                        <p>{this.state.loadedPost.body}</p>
                        <div className="Edit">
                            <button className="Delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        return post;
    }
}

export default FullPost;
```

Can someone tell what I'm missing out here and is componentWillReceiveProps a good place to change my state, if not then where should I change my state so spinner works on each user click.

Comment: Can you post the parent component that send its `props` to `<FullPost />`?

Comment: return (
            <div>
                <section className="Posts">
                   {posts}
                </section>
                <section>
                    <FullPost id={this.state.selectedPost}> /</FullPost>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <NewPost />
                </section>
            </div>
        );
**ID  of the selected post is passed to FullPost component**

Answer (score 0):

This  `if(nextProps.id)` always return `true` as long as id prop is not an empty string, `null` or `undefined`. So, even when the id prop changes, it still remains `true`.

A solution is to save the id prop to your child's state and compare with the coming id prop from the parent component.

`componentWillRecieveProps` is deprecated and considered unsafe ([unsafe componentWillRecieveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)). Instead, You can use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) or [memoization](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization)